# PHP preg_replace Character that is not a word character (\W) except:"-",".", etc

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've searched for quite a while on this one,
I want to filter a string in PHP to allow only word characters and certain other characters such as "-",".", etc..

```
preg_replace(/\W+/,'',$str)
```

For all the non-word characters it works great, adding the "except from" causes trouble.

Also, if you have a source that explains the subject thorough, I would be happy to get to the bottom of it. The subject is either very complicated or I've read bad explanations of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negated character class that includes word characters and the other characters you want to allow.

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/[^-,.\w]+/', '', $str);
```

Lots of information about regular expressions can be found at www.regular-expressions.info.